# Are articles used before titles of nouns?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Are articles used before titles of nouns? Example:

> Take the last date from **the/∅** DataStatus table.
>
> Take the last date from **the/∅** Address table.

Comment: You'd either say "...from the DataStatus table" or "...from DataStatus". Or if it's clear from context that you're talking about DataStatus you could say "...from the table". You wouldn't say "...from the DataStatus".

Answer (score 1):

> Are articles used before titles of nouns?

Yes, they can be.  The title can be considered an adjective so it's the same situation as writing *the red car*, etc.

BUt, do you *have* to use an article here?

Articles are determiners.  Here's what Wikipedia says about it in the "Zero determiner" section from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners).

> - with plural or uncountable nouns used to refer to a concept or members of a class generally: cars are useful (but the cars when
>     specific cars are being referred to); happiness is contagious (but the
>     happiness when specific happiness is referred to, as in the happiness
>     that laughter engenders...).
> - with plural or uncountable nouns used to refer to some unspecified amount of something: there are cats in the kitchen; I noticed water on
>     the floor (here it is also possible to use some cats, some water).
> - with many proper names: Tom Smith, Birmingham, Italy, Jupiter.
> - with singular common nouns in some common expressions: smiling from ear to ear, leaving town today.

The closest point that could apply would be the first one above, but you are not refering to a concept of a table, or members of a table class, but an actual instance of a date from an actual instance of a table.  A table is definitely countable anyway.  So you should use the article.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one table that's identified as "*DataStatus*" (or "*Address*"), you **can omit** the article.  It won't hurt to have the article, either, especially if in preceding text you spoke of those tables.

Comment: In the context of a data model, every table (name) is unique. However, I would _never_ omit the article when referring to _the X table_. Imagine you have physical tables (the things with legs) and there is a blue one in the room, amongst others. Would you say _put the vase on blue table_ or _put the vase on **the** blue table_? There's only one table identified by the adjective _blue_, but I bet very few, if any, native speakers would omit the article!